# Normalized output of keras layer

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I want to create a Keras model with Tensorflow background that returns a vector with norm 1. For this purpose, the model ends with the next layer:

```
main_network = Lambda(lambda t: K.l2_normalize(t, axis=1))(x)
```

I have also created a test in which I only create the model and, without training, I make a random prediction to check that the output has norm 1. But the test fails:

```
AssertionError: 0.37070954 != 1 within 0.1 delta
```

So the Lambda layer is not working correctly since it is not normalizing the output. I tried different values for the axis parameter and with all possible values, the test fails. But am I missing?

Comment: How are you making that assertion?

Comment: self.assertAlmostEqual(np.linalg.norm(vector), 1, delta=0.1)
Where vector is the result of the prediction.

Comment: @RodrigoSernaPérez np.linalg.norm returns l2-norm not 'l2-normalize'. based on my example in the answer, for a list [3, 1, 4, 3, 1] np.linalg.norm reutrn 6.

Comment: `linalg.norm` should be returning `batch_size`. So something is wrong, but it's probably somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem. For same reason, K.l2_normalize does not work with very small numbers, so I simply changed the line by this one:

```
main_network = Lambda(lambda t: K.l2_normalize(1000*t, axis=1))(x)
```

And the now the test works right!!

Comment: It's because you can't divide by zero. There is a constant `K.epsilon()`, usually `1e-7`, that is added to the denominator to avoid division by zero in (possibly) every function that has divisions in Keras.

Answer (score 0):

`L2 normalize` formula is:

```
       x
---------------
sqrt(sum(x**2))
```

For example, for an input `[3, 1, 4, 3, 1]` is `[3/6, 1/6, 4/6, 3/6, 1/6]`=`12/6` which indicates the output of `L2-normalize` is not necessary to be **one**. If you need something that normalizes the output to the sum of 1, you probably need [Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function):

Here is an example that you can check the output of the softmax is one:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda

x = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=tf.float32))
n_layer = Lambda(lambda t: K.softmax(t, axis=-1))(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(n_layer.eval())
```

Comment: I believe you posted the formula for l2 "norm", not "normalize". Should be `x / ||x||`

Comment: Softmax would only cause the sum of the elements is 1, which is not the same that being norm 1.